# Objective-C didSelectRowAtIndexPath not working having using UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using UIDocumentInteractionController to display a PDF. The user selects which PDF to display from a table view.

When I and done looking at the PDF and click the 'Done' button my table view is reload and it appears. but the table view appears frozen and cant not scroll up or down. So my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method does not work.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [datasource PDFFilePath], [ffd fileFolderName]];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    if (URL)
    {
        self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];

        [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];

        [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
    }

- (UIViewController *) documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: (UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller {
    return self;
}

- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    [_tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FileFolderData *ffd =
    [[datasource.finalData valueForKey:
      [[[datasource.finalData allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if ([ffd isFile])
    {
        [_tableView setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }

    [self performSelector:@selector(SwitchFolders:) withObject:indexPath afterDelay:0.1f];
}
```

My question is, how do I get the UITableView to work again after viewing the PDF?

I get this error

`Assigning to 'id<UITableViewDataSource> _Nullable' from incompatible type 'ViewController *const __strong`

on this line:

`_tableView.dataSource = self;`

but that can be unrelated

Other code:

```
- (void)SwitchFolders:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FileFolderData *ffd =
    [[datasource.finalData valueForKey:
      [[[datasource.finalData allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if([ffd isFolder])
    {
        [datasource GetFilesAndFolders:[ffd fileFolderName] :NO];
        [_tableView reloadData];
        [_tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }
    else if ([ffd isFile])
    {
        [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(DownloadPDF:) withObject:ffd];
    }


}
```

this is called when a cell is selected. Again selecting a cell after using UIDocumentInteractionController does not work.

More Code

```
- (void)PDFDownloadSuccess:(FileFolderData *)ffd
{
    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [datasource PDFFilePath], [ffd fileFolderName]];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

    if (URL)
    {
        self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:URL];

        [self.documentInteractionController setDelegate:self];

        [self.documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
    }

}
```

This is how PDFSuccessDownload is being called:

```
- (void)DownloadPDF:(FileFolderData *)ffd
{

    if([datasource PDFDownload_ASynch:[ffd fileFolderName]])
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(PDFDownloadSuccess:) withObject:ffd waitUntilDone:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(PDFDownloadFail:) withObject:ffd waitUntilDone:YES];
    }

}
```

And DownloadPDF is being called by the SwitchFolders method, which is called when you select a cell.

Comment: I have updated my question with additional code.

Comment: Added more methods and when they are called.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96507/discussion-between-user979331-and-matt).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by doing the following:

```
- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    [_tableView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
}
```

Setting the user interaction for the UITableView to yes after the PDF closes.